# Expression Blend for XAML in Windows 8

Tags: xaml, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml, expression-blend

Does anyone know how to get Expression Blend to work with XAML-based Metro Apps?

The developer preview only supports HTML5 in Blend. I've tried all sorts of tricks, including installing Blend 4 on the developer preview and trying to load projects into it, but nothing works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would wait - there is a chance we will get something next month with Beta release of Win8. They really don't have to be tied to one another, but one could still hope.

Meanwhile the best solution is probably to Blend things in Silverlight and just copy the XAML over to the WinRT project.

Another thing to do is to learn XAML well and type most of it by hand - that is faster for most XAML activities (not assuming you don't know XAML well, but someone else who reads it might not know it). I am a big fan of [WPF Unleashed](http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_ss_i_0_13?url=search-alias=aps&field-keywords=wpf%20unleashed&sprefix=wpf%20unleashed,aps,310) for learning the foundations of XAML.

Comment: I have to disagree: Blend is much faster than hand coding XAML once you know how to use it.  That being said, I completely agree that one should learn XAML.

Comment: It is possible either way. I suppose I never had the need to learn Blend since I started with plain XAML, so it is a lot faster for me to type something up than create it in Blend. Especially if I already know what properties to set, what to bind to etc. If I need to do animations, edit templates or vector graphics and generate random data - i turn to Blend, but let's just stop there. I suppose another option here is to use Blend but learn HTML5/WinJS and use that moving on.

Comment: I am a fairly proficient XAML developer who uses Blend a lot for design work (you just cant do that in VS - even if your good)
Do I dump XAML and dust off my javascript books, or do I need to wait (or is the HTML5/js approach going to be better supported), these are the questions I guess Im trying to answer if theres no Blend for XAML

Comment: I can't imagine no Blend for XAML, I don't believe that will be an issue.

Comment: I am sure they will add support for that in the future. It just seems that they had to put all the resources into adding support for HTML5, since it was not there at all. XAML is still important.

Comment: It's still in alpha form, the tooling comes later in the cycle.  If you choose to work with early releases you have to get comfortable with text editors.

Answer (score 1):

You said it yourself: the developer preview only supports HTML5 in Blend. Not sure what else you expect to happen. Blend 4 on regular machine should support XAML-based apps just fine.

Comment: But Blend 4 doesnt support Metro XAML apps at all - It fails to open the projects / solutions. does this mean that theres no designer tooling for WinRT XAML apps ?

Comment: Blend 4 was released in June 2010.  Developer previews are notorious for not being full featured.

Answer (score 1):

The final version of Expression Blend 5 has XAML projects as first-class citizens.

Better yet, you get it for free with Visual Studio 2012 for Windows 8!